# egrep not removing special characters

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I am having an issue with egrep which seems to omit special characters like `!@#%`.

The goal is to remove lines that have more then 3 exactly same characters. The characters don't need to be each by each.

```
111!!!qqq! #should be removed because has 4 '!'
!1!1!opop  #is fine
```

Here is what i am using:

```
cat file1.txt | egrep -vi "^(.*)(.{3,})(.*)\2(.*)$" > file2.txt
```

It works fine on nonspecial characters but it does not remove files like `!!!qwqwqwq!`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I really don't think this is link to special characters... Can you provide your test case? do you want to print the correct lines only to `file2`, or the incorrect one?

Answer (score 3):

Use this one:

```
cat input.txt | egrep -vi "(.).*\1.*\1.*\1"
```

`(.)` is capture any character, and then check whether any three same characters(in `\1`) are in next.

Comment: Note you can directly do `egrep ... input.txt`, no need to `cat`.

Comment: This should be shortened to: `egrep '(.)(.*\1){3}' input.txt`

Comment: You should not post example using `cat` to enter data into program that can read it itself.

Comment: @Jotne I only corrected OP's regex. I know basic linux commands, but not that much powerful as you guys are.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `awk` to solve this:

```
awk '{delete a;for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (++a[$i]>3) next}1' FS="" file
!1!1!opop
```

By setting `FS=""` the loop will run for every characters in the line.
It will then store this in an array named `a` increment it and test if its larger then `3`
If its larger, then use `next` to skip to next line.  If not skipped the `1` will print it.